# Google Maps library for Delphi suddenly stopped working?

Tags: google-maps, delphi, google-maps-api-3, gmlib

I'm using this library for using google maps with delphi: [GMLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmlibrary/)

This has worked fine for several months, but today when I started my application I got a lot of script errors on the page and everything broke down!

After troubleshooting all day I have concluded that this is outside of my control. To demonstrate this you only need to build & run the demo project as it demonstrate the exact same problem (loads of script errors).

The only reasonable explanation is that the js files that the library loads from the Internet has changed. However this is very hard to pinpoint.

I'm hoping the developer of the library sees this as I'm completely lost on how to even start adressing this.

Comment: Have you checked with Google to see if they've released a newer API? And are you using the latest version of this library from their last update 2 weeks ago?

Comment: I've checked the google maps api changelog and there isn't anything new there. Initially I was using an older version of gmlib (June), but I updated to the latest version to no avail. Worth to mention is that it worked perfectly yesterday, but today it stopped working everywhere (dev machines and production alike).

Comment: No new version is released, and the GMLib don't load any script from internet, the html file is loaded from a resource file. I have run the MegaDemo and work fine. Can you send my some screeshots with the error? What components do you use?

Comment: The MegaDemo works fine until you click the markers, then several script errors appear, the first one being this: http://i.imgur.com/49hK7en.png I have also built (with XE5) a MegaDemo that demonstrate the problem on both my dev machine and my machine at home, you can download it here: http://www.speedyshare.com/mdqjn/megademo.zip If there's anything else you need, please let me know!

Comment: ok, I see. It's possible that some changes are developed by Google around InfoWindows class. I will see and I will try fix it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this article is solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365774/google-maps-js-api-v3-infowindow-script-error-json-undefined

Comment: Wow! Thanks you so very, very much! Add it as an answer and I'll accept, otherwise I'll do it :)

Comment: new version released. Try whit it please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

base on this article 
[Google Maps JS API (v3) InfoWindow Script Error - JSON Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365774/google-maps-js-api-v3-infowindow-script-error-json-undefined)

Delphi's solution step is

1. modify map.html
2. rebuild gmmapres.rc（use brcc32.exe）
3. rebuild GMLib_DXE5.dproj
4. rebuild your project

Comment: Works great! I didn't rebuild GMLib_DXE5.dproj though, is that really needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the newest version 1.5.4 from [1.5.4](https://github.com/cadetill/gmlib_v1)